# How to use multiple Travis CI files inside a single repository?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, monorepo

I have a project which uses Angular on the frontend and Spring Boot on the backend.

At the moment, the frontend and the backend are in two separate repositories where I have prepared specific `travis.yaml` files like, for example, the Spring Boot app:

```
language: java
services: docker
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "mixeway" # the key of the org you chose at step #3
    token:
      secure: $SONAR_TOKEN


script:
  - mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install sonar:sonar -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dsonar.projectKey=Mixeway_MixewayBackend
  - mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
  - docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=target/mixeway-0.9.jar -t mixeway/backend:0.9 .
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
  - docker push mixeway/backend:0.9
```

The Angular `travis.yaml` is pretty similar (except that the build time of the Angular app is few times longer). I would like to merge the two repositories into one, with the code of the backend and the frontend in a single repository. I would like to have two separate pipelines, so a change in the backend code would not execute the pipeline for building the frontend image.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After facing this exact same problem with travis CI myself and not finding a satisfactory solution, I found that this can be easily done with the new [github actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions).

Basically, you create a workflow file (similar to the `.travis.yml`) for each project in the repository, which is self contained and responsible to build only the project it belongs to.

This is the basic monorepo structure:

```
.
├── .github
│   └── workflows
│       ├── project1.yml
│       ├── project2.yml
├── project1
│   └── build.gradle
├── project2
│   └── build.gradle
```

And in the workflow file itself, let's say `project1.yml`, you can specify which path should trigger the build for this project:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'project1/**'
```

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion doesn't use multiple Travis CI files (I couldn't find a way to do it either), but if someone reading this really wants to use Travis then this may meet your needs.

Travis CI lets one [list separate jobs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/#listing-individual-jobs) in a single `.travis.yml` config. These jobs run in parallel. Add a `script:` at the bottom to check if any changes were made, and I believe this will fit the bill for you.

```
# .travis.yml at the repo root

language: generic

jobs:
  include:
    - name: Detention Service
    language: node_js
    node_js: 12
    cache: npm
    env: TARGET=service
  - name: Client - Ruby RSpec
    language: ruby
    rvm: 2.6
    cache: bundler
    env: TARGET=clients/ruby/rspec

script: if .travis/build.sh $TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE $TARGET; then echo "Building '$TARGET' ..." && cd $TARGET && scripts/ci.sh; else echo "No changes detected in '$TARGET'; skipping build."; fi
```

[Works great](https://github.com/mycargus/detention/blob/master/.travis.yml) for me! Note this approach requires the following `.travis/build.sh` script at the root of your repo:

```
# .travis/build.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "x$1" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "Commit range cannot be empty"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ "x$2" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "Change path cannot be empty"
  exit 1
fi

git diff --name-only $1 | sort -u | uniq | grep $2 > /dev/null
```

and a `scripts/ci.sh` in each `TARGET` directory, for example:

```
# service/scripts/ci.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

npm ci
npm run test
```

I like that [naming each job](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/#job-names) makes investigating [builds](https://travis-ci.org/github/mycargus/detention) a little easier:

[image: Travis CI build screenshot]

Credit to Github user [arnaskro](https://github.com/arnaskro/monorepo-travis/blob/master/.travis.yml).